# How does one make a fit of $A\exp(-B|x|)$ correctly?

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose one has some data that looks exponentially distributed. Most, if not all, numerical subroutines can make the fit using [least squares fitting](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html) of the function

\begin{equation}
A\exp(-Bx),
\end{equation}

where $A,B$ are the parameters of the fit. What happens if instead one has to fit

\begin{equation}
A\exp(-B|x|),
\end{equation}

and the empirical data is not symmetric about zero? Is it correct to say that there exists two sets of fitting parameters for $x\geq0$ and $x<0$?

Comment: If you used different pairs of parameters for $\ x\ge0\ $ and $\ x<0\ $ you wouldn't be fitting the function $\ A\exp(-B|x|)\ $ to your data, but a *different* function
$$
\cases{A_1\exp\left(B_1x\right)& for $\ x<0\ $\\
A_2\exp\left(-B_2x\right)& for $\ x\ge0\ .$}
$$

Comment: Do you know how to do this for |x| and only one pair of parameters?

Comment: Just use a normal curve-fitting algorithm.  However, if your empirical data is very far from symmetric about the origin, you gave no hope of getting a close fit, regardless of what you do.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advice.